# IEqualityComparer<T> and custom type

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer, custom-type

I'm trying to compare custom type in two `List<T>` and use the `Intersect` / `Except` method. The equality is determined by three fields of this type. The equality is based on more than the ordinary condition (all fields contains the same data). I implemented of course the `IEqualityComparer<T>`. My problem is that the `GetHashCode()` method return not equal once the hashCode is not the same and this does not help me since this is not true in my case.

Is there any way to compare two custom object when equality is based on more than one condition so I can use intersect/except/distinct etc...?

Here is my code :

```
public bool Equals(ComparableObject x, ComparableObject y)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        return false;

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        return true;

    if (x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && x.Var3.Equals(y.Var3) && !x.Var2.Equals(y.Var2))
        return false;

    if (x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && !x.Var3.Equals(y.Var3) && !x.Var2.Equals(y.Var2))
        return true;


    if (!x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && x.Var3.Equals(y.Var3) && !x.Var2.Equals(y.Var2))
        return false;

    if (!x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && x.Var3.Equals(y.Var3) && x.Var2.Equals(y.Var2))
        return true;

    if (x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && !x.Var3.Equals(y.Var3) && x.Var2.Equals(y.Var2))
        return false;

    if (!x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && !x.Var3.Equals(y.Var3) && x.Var2.Equals(y.Var2))
        return false;

    if (!x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && !x.Var3.Equals(y.Var3) && !x.Var2.Equals(y.Var2))
        return false;


    return x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && x.Var1.Equals(y.Var1) && x.Var3.Equals(y.Var3);
}


public int GetHashCode(ComparableObject x)
{
    return obj.Var1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Var2.GetHashCode()^ obj.Var3.GetHashCode()
}
```

Comment: Can you post your equals method? Then we can suggest a compatible `GetHashCode` implementation. Or tell you if the `Equals` method is broken, because it violates its contract.

Comment: Is the equal hash codes necessary to equality comparison?

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh Yes, it is. `IEqualityComparer` does a two-pass job, first it gathers hash codes for all objects, then calls `Equals` for the pairs where hash code was the same. If it did a naive comparison instead, it would result in 500000 comparisons if you were to know which pairs of objects out of the total of 1000 objects are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your job to provide such `GetHashCode()` that the value it returns will be different for objects that *are* different (in as many cases as possible; you still may return same hash code for non-equal objects), and will always be same for objects that *may* be equal (in all cases; you may not return different hash code for equal objects).

For instance, if one of the three fields you compare is an `int`, you can return that field as `GetHashCode()`.

If, however, it's difficult to come up with something clever, you can return a constant, such as `42`. This way `Equals()` will be called for all object pairs, delivering expected results, although in the least performant way.

Comment: -1 for "it returns will always be different for objects that are different," that's obviously impossible to do.

Comment: is there any risk if it returns always -1 ?

Comment: @Bes-mM-bes There is no risk, there is only poorer performance.

Comment: Ok, in my case i need only to compare some objects but i hope that there' re no unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have other problems with GetHashCode in your underlying types, but this is an example of a custom type and an IEqualityComparer that returns true if only the first two fields are the same. This will allow `Except` etc. to work on the type.

```
    public class CustomType
    {
        public int Val1 { get; set; }
        public int Val2 { get; set; }
        public int Val3 { get; set; }
    }

    class CustomTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<CustomType>
    {
        public bool Equals(CustomType x, CustomType y)
        { return x.Val1 == y.Val1 && x.Val2 == y.Val2; }

        public int GetHashCode(CustomType obj)
        { return obj.Val1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Val2.GetHashCode(); }
    }
```

If your properties are not simple types as `int`, you may want to use `Equals()` instead of `==` to compare the objects.

Comment: `^` is a bit suboptimal for many uses. It's common to use something like `obj.Val1.GetHashCode() * 37 + obj.Val2.GetHashCode();`

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yes, the example was aiming to be compact but definitely agreed, there are better ways to combine the hashes than `^`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos it may be suboptimal, but what you suggested could crash if the resulting number can't be stored in an Int32.

Comment: that's why you execute it in an unchecked context. Using the `unchecked` keyword or the compiler switch.